# Clever way to aggregate multiple columns together using indice vector

Tags: r

My question is relatively simple and I already found a way in R to do it, however I'm looking for a more clever way of doing it, for educational purpose.  My solution use a loop and I always try to avoid loop as much as possible.

I have a table (or matrix):

```
set.seed(1)
tb <- matrix(round(runif(40,0,5)),4,10)
tb
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    3    3    4    5    1    4    2     4
[2,]    2    4    0    2    5    1    2    2    1     1
[3,]    3    5    1    4    2    3    0    2    4     4
[4,]    5    3    1    2    4    1    2    3    3     2
```

I want to combine different group of columns rowSumming them following a indice (or index) vector:

```
ind <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,4)
```

The for loop way:

```
res.ls <- NULL
for(i in unique(ind)) {
  res.ls[[i]] <- rowSums(subset(tb,select=ind==i))
}
do.call("cbind",res.ls)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10    7    7    4
[2,]    7    7    5    1
[3,]   12    6    6    4
[4,]   10    6    8    2
```

I'm sure there is a smarter way to do that.  Any hint?

Comment: If you have the memory available to transpose twice, see `?rowsum`; btw `set.seed` is a function that needs to be called, not assigned (`set.seed(1)`)

Comment: take the transpose and then group_by and sum it! Sorry i didn't see the above comment. same thought

Comment: @alexis_laz, interresting point about memory.  For set.seed, in french we say that it was a "bubble in the brain"...  sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like your result match your input, but following your logic, you can use `rowsum` but on the transposed version of the original matrix:

```
t(rowsum(t(tb), ind))

#      1 2 3 4
#[1,] 15 4 6 3
#[2,] 17 8 5 3
#[3,] 11 4 5 3
#[4,] 12 2 6 4
```

---

Or use `apply()` function on every row with `rowsum()` to avoid transposing twice:

```
t(apply(tb, 1, rowsum, ind))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   15    4    6    3
#[2,]   17    8    5    3
#[3,]   11    4    5    3
#[4,]   12    2    6    4
```

---

If you have a data frame, this might be more efficient as it doesn't convert the data frame to matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(tb)
do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df, ind), rowSums)) # use split.default to split data 
# frames as multiple data frames by columns and apply rowSums to each sub data frame

#      1 2 3 4
#[1,] 15 4 6 3
#[2,] 17 8 5 3
#[3,] 11 4 5 3
#[4,] 12 2 6 4
```

Comment: About the result not matching, you are right @Psidom, it was a copy paste and set.seed problem.  I've fixed it.  For your proposition, it could work but I was reluctant (with or without a good reason) to transpose because of the fact I was using a data.frame.

Comment: If you have a data frame, you probably want to reflect that in your question? There should be better solutions with data frame.

Comment: Ho...  I really like your edited apply option!  I didn't know the rowsum (vs rowSums) function.

Comment: Really like your last edit (again).  Three ways of doing the same thing in R and learning two functions (rowsum and split.default), it's exactly what I meant by "for educationnal purpose".  Thanks.  It could be nice to compare the methods for speed.  My original table is not big enough for that but I'll keep it in mind for further use.

Comment: I was curious so I did test the speed (see below).  Your data.frame option was the most efficient. @Psidom

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm suppose to post this as an answer, but I wanted to test the efficiency of all 5 methods presented here (my loop, @Psidom 3 answers and @Imo's answer).  I've made my data bigger:

```
set.seed(1)
tb <- matrix(round(runif(40000000,0,15)),40000,1000)
ind <- round(runif(1000,1,300))
```

and ran all options:

```
 res.ls <- NULL
 system.time({
 for(i in unique(ind)) {
   res.ls[[i]] <- rowSums(subset(tb,select=ind==i))
 }
 res1 <- do.call("cbind",res.ls)
 })
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.60        0.04        0.64 

 system.time(
 res2 <- t(rowsum(t(tb), ind))
 )
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.68        0.02        0.70 

 system.time(
 res3 <- t(apply(tb, 1, rowsum, ind))
 )
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      20.01        0.21       20.24 

 system.time(
 res4 <- sapply(split(tb, rep(ind, each=nrow(tb))), function(x) rowSums(matrix(x, nrow(tb))))
 )
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
      58.68        0.42       59.13 


 df1 <- data.frame(tb)
 system.time(
 res5 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df1, ind), rowSums)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
        0.3         0.0         0.3
```

with:

```
 all(res1==res2)
[1] TRUE

 all(res1==res3)
[1] TRUE

 all(res1==res4)
[1] TRUE

 all(res1==res5)
[1] TRUE
```

So it seems the loop is not that slow and the data.frame version is the best.  Interesting results!

Comment: Nice benchmark. I am surprised how efficient the second method is, even though it avoids transposing the matrix twice. Probably a even better way for the last option is `as.data.frame(lapply(split.default(df1, ind), rowSums))`.

Comment: I've doubled the size of the data to test @Psidom last comment, and you see a little gain: 0.62 for the new data.frame method vs 0.67 for the old one.  May be a useful gain in some context, but not for mine!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a second method using `split` and `rowSums`:

```
    sapply(split(tb, rep(ind, each=nrow(tb))), function(x) rowSums(matrix(x, nrow(tb))))
      1 2 3 4
[1,] 10 7 7 4
[2,]  7 7 5 1
[3,] 12 6 6 4
[4,] 10 6 8 2
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
tb <- matrix(round(runif(40,0,5)),4,10)
ind <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,4)
```

Comment: I've tested the speed of your answer (see below), it works and gives the good result, but the speed is problematic. @Imo

Comment: Wow. that is a stark difference. Thanks for doing the speed comparisons. I'll have to think a bit on where the huge bottlenecks are in this method.